# How to implement Rest API that supports partial response and nested queries with nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, facebook-graph-api, graphql

I've been wondering how to implement an api systems like facebook graph, google, and linkedin partial responses as described [here](https://blog.octo.com/en/design-a-rest-api/#partial)

**Facebook**

```
GET /clients/007?fields=firstname,name  
200 OK
{
"id":"007",
"firstname":"James",
"name":"Bond"
}
```

**Google**

```
GET /clients/007?fields=firstname,name,address(street)   <--- nested query
200 OK

{
"id":"007",
"firstname":"James",
"name":"Bond",
"address":{"street":"Horsen Ferry Road"}
}
```

I had a look at facebook GraphQL library that seems to provide the solution for partial response, but it seems to be more complex, and difficult to implement

Is there any nodejs libraries that can provide such interface with permission management to control what data can be accessed by which user